# Getting Key error despite column name being present while using group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df & I am trying to do  a groupby on the mail column in the df to see count of unique id's associated with each mail. I expect to see Mail then Name of the person and then ID and then Count of unique ID's associated with that mail.

Below is my code-

```
grouped=df.groupby('Mail')[['NAME','ID']].apply(list).reset_index()
grouped['COUNT']=grouped['ID'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
grouped[grouped['COUNT']>1]
```

Error:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3505, in

 DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]
```

Note -
when I am using the exact same code without ['NAME'] then it works fine.

```
grouped=df.groupby('Mail')['ID'].apply(list).reset_index()
grouped['COUNT']=grouped['ID'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
grouped[grouped['COUNT']>1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please follow the link shared by @PandaKim and provide a MRE.

Comment: @Pranav167 can there be different 'NAME' in the same 'ID'?

Comment: yes, there  could be different name in the same id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but what you're asking doesn't make much sense to me.
if you change this line of code:

```
grouped['COUNT']=grouped['ID'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
```

with:

```
grouped['COUNT']=grouped['mail'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
print(grouped)
```

Your code must work.
Check the terminal and you will see that the NAME and ID fields no longer exist in the dataframe,
It's why your code fails.